# (Bootstrap) add margin after bootstrap card

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to know if there's a way to add a margin after a bootstrap card so it doesnt override the text below? So basically when I try to shrink the width of the window of my browser the text in the card above gets crammed and starts new lines but the text below stays in the same line. I really don't know how I should explain this properly but I will provide Code + screenshots.
The spacing should always be like this:

[image: How it should look like]

When I shrink the window it looks like this:

[image: How it actually looks]

```html
<div class="card bg-secondary text-white">
          <img class="card-img" src="images/mainbackground.jpg" alt="Card image" height="500" width="100%">
          <div class="card-img-overlay">
              <div class="jumbotron">
                  <div class="container">
                      <br>
                      <h1 class="display-3 text-secondary">Hello, world!</h1>
                      <p class="text-secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                      </p>
                      <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="https://www.futureride.at/shop/" role="button">Zum Shop &raquo;</a></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      Text after the card
```

Comment: You need to write `media Queries` to get responsive

Comment: I assume the main problem is the fixed height of 500px for the image/container... on mobile devices there's not enough horizontal space to display all the Lorem Ipsum contents, so it flows outside of the div

Answer (score 0):

You could do it one of two way:  you could add inline style to the card.  Something like this `<div class="card bg-secondary text-white" style="margin-bottom: 5px;>` or your could add a style to the card in your CSS file like:

```
.card {
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

I would also recommend putting the text in a div or p.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure is it the solution that u want to achieve. Below is my solution.

```
<div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <br>
            <h1 class="display-3 text-secondary">Hello, world!</h1>
            <p class="text-secondary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="https://www.futureride.at/shop/" role="button">Zum Shop &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
<style type="text/css">
    .jumbotron{
        margin: 0;
    }
    .outerDiv{
        padding: 1.5rem;
        background: url(images/BG.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>
```

I didn't use bootstrap card. I added the outerDiv myself. Hope it would help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think the jumbotron is intended to be used inside a card... I would keep it as it is and then style it the way I want it.

Example:

https://codepen.io/Kidkie/pen/jvMQzj

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/2000/800); ">
  <div class="jumbotron-inner">
    <div class="jumbotron-content">
      <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
      <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="https://www.futureride.at/shop/" role="button">Zum Shop &raquo;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">Text after the card</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">Text after the card</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">Text after the card</div>
  </div>
</div>
```